# What controls might remove or obscure the vertical limit of a WPF RichTextBox Control under them?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

### Problem:

I have a RichTextBox control, in a Grid, on a Page, which a Frame then shows on my Window.

When I dump many lines of data into it, grows vertically well past the bottom of the screen, pushing lower controls out of visible range.

I've been reading various articles that seem to overlap with my problem, but not finding any answers I'm able to draw a solution from. The only applicable practice from what I've found -- but very poor practice I am not interested in using -- is to hardcode the MaxHeight of the RichTextBox, or whatever object I put it inside of. Which I consider totally unacceptable.

### Example that works properly:

I tried a new, empty application with the main window having nothing but a Frame for the Page, as shown here:

```
<Window x:Class="WPFTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow">
    <Grid  MinHeight="350" MinWidth="525">
        <Frame Source="TestPage1.xaml" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The Page defined as:

```
<Page x:Class="WPFTest.TestPage1"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
      mc:Ignorable="d" 
    Title="TestPage1">

    <Grid  MinHeight="350" MinWidth="525">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="27" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="27" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBox Name="txtName" Grid.Row="0">John Doe</TextBox>
        <RichTextBox Name="txtOutput" Grid.Row="1" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" />
        <Button Name="btnFillData" Grid.Row="2" Click="btnFillData_Click">Fill Data</Button>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

And it worked as expected. The button dumps 500 lines of data into the RichTextBox and it leaves all controls visible in the Window. A scrollbar appears on the RichTextBox itself and I'm a happy camper.

### Code exhibiting the problem:

I don't have any idea at the moment what to include from my application that could change the behavior of the Page, the Grid or the RichTextbox to make it run well past the bottom of the screen. So forgive the long-winded dump. But here's my main window's XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="Tools.MainWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="Window1" Height="550" Width="750">
    <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"><!-- This being 'Auto' or 'Enabled' is the only reason the app is useable right now, it puts a scrollbar on the Window instead of the RichTextBox -->
        <StackPanel Background="#666633">
            <TabControl Name="tabTools" TabStripPlacement="Left" Background="#CC9" Foreground="White" BorderBrush="#C2C2A3" Margin="0,10,0,0">
                <TabItem Header="First Tool" IsSelected="True" Background="#999966" Foreground="#993300" Height="25">
                    <Frame Source="pgFirstTool.xaml" />
                </TabItem>
                <TabItem Header="Other Tool" Background="#999966" Foreground="#993300" Height="25" Margin="-2,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                    <Frame Source="pgOtherTool.xaml" />
                </TabItem>
                <TabItem Header="Project Related Tool" Background="#999966" Foreground="#993300" Height="25" Margin="-2,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                    <Frame Source="pgProjectTool.xaml" />
                </TabItem>
                <TabItem Header="Project Tool 2" Background="#999966" Foreground="#993300" Height="25" Margin="-2,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                    <Frame Source="pgProjectTool2.xaml" />
                </TabItem>
                <TabItem Header="Some Viewer" Background="#999966" Foreground="#993300" Height="25">
                    <Frame Source="pgSomeViewer.xaml" />
                </TabItem>
                <TabItem Header="Folder Tool" Background="#999966" Foreground="#993300" Height="25">
                    <Frame Source="pgFolderTool.xaml" />
                </TabItem>
            </TabControl>
            <Button Name="cmdExit" Margin="0,4,0,0" Click="cmdExit_Click">Exit</Button>
        </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Window>
```

The Page that houses the problematic RichTextBox is:

```
<Page x:Class="Tools.pgFolderTool"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      Title="pgFolderSizes">

    <Grid MinWidth="500" MinHeight="450">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="27" />
            <RowDefinition Height="27" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="27" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="120" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="30" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Label Name="lblStoreOn" Grid.Column="0">Store on:</Label>
            <TextBox Name="txtFolder" Grid.Column="1" Padding="2" Background="#DDA" Text="B:\CSOPhase2" />
            <Button Name="cmdSelectFolder" Grid.Column="2" Width="25" Content="..." Click="cmdSelectFolder_Click" Padding="2" />
        </Grid>

        <Button Name="cmdRun" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Click="cmdRun_Click" IsDefault="True" VerticalAlignment="Center">Run</Button>


        <RichTextBox Name="txtOutput" Background="#DDA" />
        <ListBox Name="lstResults" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" SelectionChanged="lstResults_SelectionChanged" ListBoxItem.MouseDoubleClick="lstResults_MouseDoubleclick" />

        <RichTextBox Name="txtStatus" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Background="#DDA" />
        <RichTextBox Name="txtThings" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Background="#DDA" />
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

I am virtually certain I don't do any UI manipulation from the code-behind, although I may test that in my new trial application to make myself absolutely certain. I believe the issue is a nuance to how these the objects work including each other, and the RichTextBox.

Any help tracking this down would be genuinely appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

### Answer

So I just removed the ScrollViewer and the StackPanel from the Window, and put a Grid in as such:

```
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" /><!-- TabControl here -->
        <RowDefinition Height="27" /><!-- Exit button here -->
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

And now it works properly.

I believe that means that either the ScrollViewer or the StackPanel was breaking the sizing functionality of the RichTextBox. If I had to bet, I'd say probably the StackPanel.

Posting anyway in case someone has a similar weird problem with control sizing.